# Yum can't download, but curl is fine?

Tags: rhel, yum

I'm creating a local copy of rpmforge on a RHEL5 host.

```
# reposync --repoid=rpmforge --download_path=/var/www/html/yum

# cd /var/www/html/yum/rpmforge; createrepo --database .
```

I have a repository entry for this local repo, in addition to the remote repo. Then I do a `yum clean all` and `yum list local-rpmforge`.

```
# yum list local-rpmforge
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from ULN.
http://${hostname}.${fqdn}/yum/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout: <urlopen error timed out>
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: local-rpmforge. Please verify its path and try again.
```

However, curling the url gets me immediate output!

```
# curl http://${hostname}.${fqdn}/yum/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repomd xmlns="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/repo">
  <data type="other_db">
...
```

(`${hostname}` and `${fqdn}` are obfuscations to appease my security group. In the actual commands, the explicit internal hostnames and subdomains are given. This problem is entirely internal. No firewalls or proxys are involved or needed. My test server and client are on the same subnet. wget downloads the file just as easily as curl does.)

What in the world? This is not the only repository to fail, but other local repositories created with the same methods are fine.

Comment: ${hostname} and ${fqdn} are environment variables? Your shell will replace them in the curl case, but are you sure yum internally replaces them too?

Comment: They're obfuscations. This is a work environment, and security says I can't share hostnames or internal subdomains. :)

Comment: What is the output of: 1: `ping ${hostname}.${fqdn}` and 2. `wget http://${hostname}.${fqdn}/yum/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml`

Comment: Work environment smells like proxy. Are you aware of any proxy settings?

Comment: The initial downloads from the external sites go through a proxy. This problem is all internal once I have the packages moved inside the firewall. I've downloaded. I've created the local repository database. The ${hostname} and ${fqdn} values are entirely internal.

Comment: Ping is fine (again, this problem is entirely around local/internal hosts and subdomains). wget behaves just like curl. I get the file just fine.

Comment: What are the Timeout Values on the machines that work?  Are the yum configs identical?

Comment: /etc/yum.conf is entirely default on both client and server, and none of the repositories have repo-specific timeouts set.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't quite true. I do have `proxy`, `proxy_user`, and `proxy_password` in /etc/yum.conf. However, adding `proxy=_none_` to the individual local repositories does not change behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it again! This time, I figured out what I did a year ago, and repeated it.

This particular host holds the local yum repositories, so `/etc/yum.conf` is configured with proxy information to get out of my firewall and download the current RHEL packages.

However, comma, I neglected to add the line `proxy=_none_` to the *internal* repository configurations in the internal `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` files. So, yum was trying to hit the proxy for hosts inside the firewall and the firewall was rightfully refusing the connection.

So, the final comments above had it right. It was the proxy, but in the reverse meaning. I was trying to hit the proxy when I shouldn't have been.

Comment: I am having this issue now but have no proxy settings, even `yum-config-manager` returns `proxy = False`. `curl` works. Stumped.

Comment: In my case, adding a proxy entry has actually helped. yum seems to ignore environment http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables (at least partly!)